Cycling of Lexicographic simplex method
I am studying the cycling of simplex method. I know that there is a lexicographic rule to prevent looping of the simplex method, and I also know that this rule should be applied to a lexicographically valid simplex table (this is a table in which the first non-zero coefficients are positive). But I know that there is a way to loop the lexicographic simplex method, for this you need to select the appropriate lexicographically invalid simplex table. Can you please help with this task to find such table (I also know that at least such a table has a dimension of 3 (constraints) by 7 (variables))
I tried to find such a table by iteration (given the fact that such a table starts with 3 constraints and 7 variables). Ideally, I expect to get such a table
I have this code:
import pandas as pd
import copy
import math

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)

Bi = [1, 0, 0]
vectorC = [0, 0, 0, 2.2361, -2, 0, -4, -3.6180, -3.236, -3.6180, -0.764]
coeficients_Aij = [
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0.3090, -0.6180, -0.8090, -0.3820, 0.8090, 0.3820, 0.3090, 0.6180],
    [0, 0, 1, 1.4635, 0.3090, 1.4635, -0.8090, -0.9045, -0.8090, 0.4635, 0.309],
]

def is_Lexicographic(matrix):
    flag = True
    for i in matrix:
        for j in i:
            if j == 0:
                continue
            elif j > 0:
                break
            elif j < 0:
                return False
    return flag

spCol = []
strNum = len(Bi)
xNum = len(coeficients_Aij[0])
spBasises = []
spBasises.append([i for i in range(xNum - strNum + 1, xNum + 1)])

spCol.append("_X_")
for i in range(xNum):
    spCol.append(f"X{i + 1}")

def isclose(a, b, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0):
    return abs(a-b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)
def isTableValide(matrix_Aij):
    flag = True
    for i in range(xNum + 1):
        if matrix_Aij[strNum][i] < 0:
            count = 0
            for j in range(strNum):
                if not (isclose(matrix_Aij[j][i], 0)) and matrix_Aij[j][i] > 0:
                    count += 1
            if count == 0:
                print("FLAG")
                print(matrix_Aij[0][0])
                print(matrix_Aij[strNum][xNum])
                return False
    return True

def reverseC(vectorC):
    result = []
    for i in vectorC:
        result.append(-i)
    return result


print("START TABLE:")
symplex_Table = coeficients_Aij
symplex_Table.insert(strNum, reverseC(vectorC))
symplex_Table[strNum].insert(0, 0)
for i in range(strNum):
    symplex_Table[i].insert(0, Bi[i])
init_Symplex_Table = pd.DataFrame(columns=spCol, data=symplex_Table)
print(init_Symplex_Table)

def lexicSymplexMethod(matrix_Aij):
    Max_Xj = 0
    Max_Yi = 0

    if not(isTableValide(matrix_Aij)):
        print("There is no solution due to the unlimited function")
        return 1

    while matrix_Aij[strNum][Max_Xj] >= 0:
        Max_Xj += 1
        if Max_Xj > xNum:
            print('FIND OPTIMAL SOLUTION')
            return [matrix_Aij, 2]
    for Xj in range(Max_Xj, xNum + 1):
        flag = True
        c = 1
        if abs(matrix_Aij[strNum][Xj]) > abs(matrix_Aij[strNum][Max_Xj]) and matrix_Aij[strNum][Xj] != 0 and \
                matrix_Aij[strNum][Xj] < 0:
            while c <= len(matrix_Aij) - 2:
                if not (matrix_Aij[c][Xj] >= 0):
                    flag = False
                    break
                c = c + 1
            if flag:
                Max_Xj = Xj
    #while matrix_Aij[Max_Yi][Max_Xj] <= 0:
    while isclose(matrix_Aij[Max_Yi][Max_Xj], 0) or matrix_Aij[Max_Yi][Max_Xj] < 0:
        Max_Yi += 1
        if Max_Yi > strNum:
            print("There is no solution due to the unlimited function")
            return 1
    for Yi in range(strNum + 1):
        if matrix_Aij[Yi][Max_Xj] <= 0:
            continue
        if matrix_Aij[Yi][Max_Xj] > 0 and abs(matrix_Aij[Yi][0] / matrix_Aij[Yi][Max_Xj]) < abs(
                matrix_Aij[Max_Yi][0] / matrix_Aij[Max_Yi][Max_Xj]):
            Max_Yi = Yi
        if matrix_Aij[Yi][Max_Xj] > 0 and abs(matrix_Aij[Yi][0] / matrix_Aij[Yi][Max_Xj]) == abs(
                matrix_Aij[Max_Yi][0] / matrix_Aij[Max_Yi][Max_Xj]):
            for i in range(1, strNum + 1):
                if matrix_Aij[Yi][Max_Xj] > 0 and abs(matrix_Aij[Yi][i] / matrix_Aij[Yi][Max_Xj]) == abs(
                        matrix_Aij[Max_Yi][i] / matrix_Aij[Max_Yi][Max_Xj]):
                    pass
                if matrix_Aij[Yi][Max_Xj] > 0 and abs(matrix_Aij[Yi][i] / matrix_Aij[Yi][Max_Xj]) < abs(
                        matrix_Aij[Max_Yi][i] / matrix_Aij[Max_Yi][Max_Xj]):
                    Max_Yi = Yi
                    break
    Copy_matrix_Aij = copy.deepcopy(matrix_Aij)
    for Yi in range(strNum + 1):
        for Xj in range(xNum + 1):
            if Yi == Max_Yi:
                Copy_matrix_Aij[Yi][Xj] = matrix_Aij[Yi][Xj] / matrix_Aij[Max_Yi][Max_Xj]
            if Yi != Max_Yi:
                Copy_matrix_Aij[Yi][Xj] = matrix_Aij[Yi][Xj] - matrix_Aij[Max_Yi][Xj] * matrix_Aij[Yi][Max_Xj] / \
                                          matrix_Aij[Max_Yi][Max_Xj]
    return Copy_matrix_Aij


iterated_Symplex_Table = copy.deepcopy(symplex_Table)
i = 0
while True:
    print(f"Iteration № {i}")
    i += 1
    outCurrent_Symplex_Table = pd.DataFrame(columns=spCol, data=iterated_Symplex_Table)
    print(outCurrent_Symplex_Table)
    print()
    print()
    print()
    iterated_Symplex_Table = lexicSymplexMethod(iterated_Symplex_Table)
    if iterated_Symplex_Table == 1:
        print("NO SOLUTION!!!")
        break
    if len(iterated_Symplex_Table) == 2 and iterated_Symplex_Table[1] == 2:
        print('FIND OPTIMAL SOLUTION')
        break


In fact, the task is to select such values in the variables : coeficients_Aij , Bi, VectorC, so that the program loops
In trying to find an answer to this question, I relied on the following sources:
theory about simplex algorithms;
theory   about lexicographical simplex metod;
Visualizing cycles in simplex method - for to understand and represent the looping process;
here is an example of the code and an example of the implementation of the usual simplex method and the lexicographic simplex method and the principle of their operation is explained

I have no idea what this is asking. Can you show expected and actual output, and add links to descriptions of the theory?

Also, this is not a stand-alone MCVE. symplex_Table is undefined.

sorry, i fixed my code

in actual result(with the values of the variables Bi, vectorC, coeficients_Aij presented in the example), my program out: "FIND OPTIMAL SOLUTION", but I want the program to go into an infinite loop (i.e. the condition for exiting the while loop never repeats). To do this, I need to select the appropriate values in the arrays Bi, vectorC and coeficients_Aij

I added links to descriptions of the theory

Is there any reason that you aren't using Numpy?

In my opinion, it is not needed here, why connect third-party libraries if you can write it yourself. Maybe I don't understand something and in this case there is a meaning, then please explain it

In this case that's a very poor decision. Numpy will be orders of magnitude faster, and will make a lot of your code more terse.

Also: you're using Pandas, which is a third-party library and depends on Numpy anyway.

I use this library for beautiful table output. I implement all the rest of the logic myself
